# Cannot find name 'google' - while using google maps on Ionic2

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

I wrote the following `html/js` code which is working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <script src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

      <script>
        function loadMap() {
            var lat = 1;
            var lng = 0;
            var pos = "x";

            var mapOptions = {
               center:new google.maps.LatLng(45.10,20.10),
               zoom:5
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("sample"),mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: map.getCenter(),

               icon: {
                  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.BACKWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                  scale: 5,
                  strokeWeight:2,
                  strokeColor:"#B40404"
               },

               draggable:true,
               map: map,
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
                lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
                lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
                pos = " - " + lat + " - " + lng + " - ";
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: pos
                });
               infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

         }
      </script>
   </head>   
   <body onload = "loadMap()">
      <div id = "sample" style = "width:580px; height:400px;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I did not use any API key `<script src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">`, for me it is enough this kind of usage.

Second step of my developing is to use this code in my Ionic2 app. So I start trying to load a simple map in my app but I'm facing some issues.

My ionic2 project is with a tab template, and as a first step I set the following row in my `src/index.html`

```
<head>
...
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
...
</head>
```

Then in my related page (SearchPage) I just inserted the following content in the `html` file:

```
<ion-content>
  <div #map id="map"></div>  
</ion-content>
```

and the `ts` file looks like this:

```
export class SearchPage {
    @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
    map: any;
    ...
    text: any;
    lat : any; 
    lon : any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public recoshService: Recosh, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(
            pos => {
                this.lat = pos.coords.latitude;
                this.lon = pos.coords.longitude;
                this.loadMap();
                this.loadGuides();
            },
            err => {
        .....
loadMap(){
        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lon);
        let mapOptions = {
            center: latLng,
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
```

When Ionic2 is building errors are shown and the transpile fails. All of them are related the following error:

> Cannot find name 'google'

It seems I'm using the js library in a wrong way. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just Typescript complaining about knowing nothing of what `google` is. You can fix it by just declaring the property like this:

```
// imports ...

declare var google: any

@Component({
    ...
})
export class ....
```

Comment: the error itself is not still there, but the map it is not shown in the page. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Sebaferraras I think the answer is partially answered, because the cannot find is ok as I said, but what about google api key, can I make it working without as per my html page?

Comment: @pittuzzo I think you can use it without setting the api key (although it's recommended to sign up and create one, it's free after all...). Otherwise you'll see an error in the console saying explicitly that you must include the key to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing googlemaps:

```
$npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev
```

Comment: This npm package has been deprecated. It's now `@types/google.maps`.

Answer (score 0):

Just import the types for Google Maps:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/google.maps
```